# Why can't Ubuntu read external volume files after I recursively { chmod +r and remove ACL }?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions, chmod

The commands I used are:  `sudo chmod -RN /volume` and `sudo chmod -R +r  /volume`

The external volume is a backup of OSX home folders.
The above made it only possible to read what contents is in the home folders (in Desktop, in Documents) but not the files or sub-directories.
In OSX I can see that all the files have read permission and no ACL.
In Ubuntu in GUI it reads "The permission of 'folder' could not be determined"
In shell in shows question marks for the permissions of the contents in Home Folders.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
Finally I applied more commands, don't know which one did it:

(1) chmod -R a+rX /volume;

(2) find /volume -type f -exec chmod -N {} \;

I expected the first two recursive commands in the question to solve it though, I don't know why it didnt happen, you can write any comments if you know why.